# ¿Cómo aprendiste a programar?

Tags: python, c#, lenguaje-compilado

Llevo un rato familiarizandome con la programación, sin embargo nunca he sido capaz de terminar algún proyecto tanto en poco tiempo como por mí misma.

Se me complica mucho al fin entender muchas cosas a pesar de que he repasado varias veces.

En donde más he trabajado es en Python y C# (visual basic)

Comment: Es la segunda pregunta de tu autoria que leo y la verdad parece que no comprendes el propósito de [es.so]. Lamentablemente el sistema automáticamente te bloqueará y tu capacidad para seguir usando el sitio se verá limitada. Te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y que leas [ask]. Cuando tengas realmente un problema de programación, tu pregunta será bienvenida. Saludos

Comment: Con más rep puedes charlar de esto en el [chat].

Comment: creo que ya conseguiste suficientes puntos para que vayas por la sala de chat :D

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

- Entra a github y revisa proyectos terminados del lenguaje que elijas. Descargalos, personalizalo a tu gusto y luego puedes subir proyectos a tu repositprio personal.
- Compra libros fisicos, realiza anotaciones y resumenes.
- Fijate en la medium.com hay mucho codigo de ejemplos para comenzar cualquier proyecto, tambien explican conceptos.

Comment: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/3217#3217

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo, seguiré los consejos :)